# How to break up HTML document to implement modularity?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm creating a web-site and use html to build page layout. So i have one big html document  `index.html`. There are header, middle section and footer. Many scripts are used for form checks, animations, slider and etc. Slider has a several background images and different content for each slide. So `index.html` has a lot of stuff in it and when the user loads it first time quite bit of traffic is used. 
When user fills up login form, client side jquery script checks form and then data is posted to php script where server side checks are performed and session started. After successful response from server i want `index.html` to reload with different header. I came up with two solutions for this:

*

- I can load different  document using AJAX into header container.
- I can redirect to another html document(for example `index2.html` that has exact same code with exception that header container part is changed.

I don't like both of the solutions. By using AJAX  i can avoid forcing user to reload all the traffic. But it seems not elegant for me as reloading only header will make white square appear in that section which will break user's design experience and it looks clunky. But while it's asynchronous action is there any way to show something for user in header area while document is loading?
Second solution is obviously bad as that will cause tons's of code repetitions traffic reload and etc.

If i used `PHP` for building my project i could broke document into modules (header.php, midSection.php, footer.php and etc.) So my `index.php` file would consist of `includes` and i could just had `onloginheader.php` file created and `include` changed to it on page  reload.
 Is there any way to do something similar to this in html document?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand very well but, that may help you.

```
    $('#header > #loading').show();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "email=email@example.com&password=password"
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(data) {
        if(data) {
            if(data.status == 'success')
                $('#header > #memberArea').html(data.memberAreaCode);
            else
                $('#header > #loginError').show();

            $('#header > #loading').hide();
        }
    });
```

Loading represents a div container, may be opacity:0.8 and has a loading indicator in it. It will shown on your header section and default css value is display:none;

When you send a login request, first of all you should show loading screen to user so he cannot understand the changes on your header part. After that, if login success, you may make the changes that come from serverside, or you can just set a username via jQuery. And rest of all, you will hide loading screen again. And thats all.

Comment: Why having `#el-id > #el2-id` path? Why not only `#el2-id` ?

Comment: Also, considering that most of the times, `data` on ajax calls is dynamic, would be better to use an object: data: `{ email: 'foo@bar.com', password : '123' }`. This way you can avoid monstrously strings and ugly concatenations between js variables and strings.

Comment: @IonutStaicu yes, thanks for your help. I have just try to give him a way to do it. This is a code snippet from my old works. I also don't like to send important data via ajax :)